# ¿Cómo especificar reglas de elementos específicos en un reset CSS?

Tags: css

Suelo usar un pequeño reset CSS para pruebas:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin    : 0;
    padding   : 0;
}
```

Si se van a crear listas y no se quiere que aparezcan los *discos*, se puede añadir la regla para el elemento `ul` y quedaría:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin    : 0;
    padding   : 0;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Si bien, como `list-style` solo afecta a las listas (creo), el siguiente *reset* también funciona (Chromiun / Firefox):

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin    : 0;
    padding   : 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

¿Esta última aproximación puede presentar algún tipo de problema?

Answer (score 0):

Consideremos que el uso de `list-style: algo;` es una sintaxis corta para las siguientes propiedades<sup>1</sup>:

- list-style-type
- list-style-image
- list-style-position

Dado lo anterior y basándonos en el hecho de que lo estás dejando bajo el contexto del selector universal, estará afectando a todas las listas tanto: `ordenadas` como las `desordenadas`

**Ejemplo**

```html
      <style>
        * {
          list-style: none;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
    <ol>
      <li>Cuatro</li>
      <li>Cinco</li>
      <li>Seis</li>
    </ol>
```

Entonces como *reset* solo lo deberías estar aplicando si:

- No tienes mas listas que se puedan ver afectadas
- No importa que la regla CSS se aplique a la totalidad de posibles listas que puedas tener

Por otro lado en este punto quizás el tema de las clases para este escenario sea mas últi si consideramos lo siguiente:

- Todas las listas que deseemos sean modificadas quitando la viñeta han de tener una clase a la que por medio de CSS le aplicaremos la regla que la elimine y así evitamos que sea una instrucción general para todos los listados

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <style>
      .lista-estilizada {
        list-style: none;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="lista-estilizada">
      <li>Elemento 1</li>
      <li>Elemento 2</li>
      <li>Elemento 3</li>
      <li>Elemento 4</li>
      <li>Elemento 5</li>
    </ul>
    <ol>
      <li>Cuatro</li>
      <li>Cinco</li>
      <li>Seis</li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="lista-estilizada">
      <li>Elemento 6</li>
      <li>Elemento 7</li>
      <li>Elemento 8</li>
      <li>Elemento 9</li>
      <li>Elemento 10</li>
    </ol>
```

**Fuentes**

- [list-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/list-style)